# Powershell Split function not working in VSTS Release pipeline

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script which takes multiple webapps(comma separated) as input.
I am splitting these webapps using powershell split function and configuring webapps by traversing each one of them using for-each loop.
Everything works fine in Powershell editor but when I configure the same script to VSTS release pipeline , split function doesn't work and which results in failure.

Input : devopstestwebapp1,devopstestwebapp2

Code : $WebAppName = $WebAppName.Split(',')

Output (After Split) : devopstestwebapp1 devopstestwebapp2

Error :  The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/devopstestwebapp1 
devopstestwebapp2' under resource group 'DevOpsResourseGroup' was not found.

Following is my powershell script

```
# Parameters
param (   
    [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $AADAppID,
    [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $AADKey,
    [Parameter(Position=2,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $TenantId,
    [Parameter(Position=3,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ResourceGroupName,
    [Parameter(Position=4,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ServerName,
    [Parameter(Position=5,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $RGLocation,
    [Parameter(Position=6,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $WebAppName,
    [Parameter(Position=7,mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $SubscriptionName
 )

    # Connect to Azure

    $ssAADKey = ConvertTo-SecureString $AADKey -AsPlainText -Force
    $psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AADAppID, $ssAADKey)

    Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCredential -Subscription $SubscriptionName -TenantId $TenantId     
    write-host $WebAppName
    $WebAppName = $WebAppName.Split(',')
     write-host $WebAppName
    Foreach ($servicename in $WebAppName)
    {
        write-host $servicename

    }
```

[image]

Comment: how confident are you that the `.Split()` method is _not working_ as opposed to something in the VSTS release pipeline is interfering with the split results?

Comment: Since you are using the same variable name `$WebAppName`, you'll end up with an array where you expect it to be a string. Use something like `foreach ($appName in $WebAppName.Split(',')) {...}`

Comment: I tried foreach ($appName in $WebAppName.Split(',')) , but still not splitted the string

Comment: @kartikiyer - if it really is not splitting on the comma ... then you don't have a comma in the string. [*grin*] confirm that it does have a comma ... and then confirm that something ELSE is forcing the resulting array into a string. ///// you likely will need to post the actual code being run to get any more detail.

Comment: Added my powershell script , where i am trying to take webappname as input from release pipeline variables and splitting the same

Comment: that looks like it SHOULD work. [*grin*] it's time to add some logging to see what your actual input is. please recall that what PoSh _shows on screen_ is NOT always what the variable _contains_ since the screen output is often `stringified`.

Comment: Updated powershell script with log statement and also attached output image, I am getting correct output (string gets splitted) , if I add inline powershell script and hardcode my values in Azure Powershell task in VSTS release pipeline.

Comment: @kartikiyer - using `Write-Host $ArrayVar` will stringify the array and give you `ItemOne ItemTwo`. try it in the ISE or your powershell console. [*grin*] instead, use `Wrtie-Output $ArrayVar`.

Comment: Not working , tried changing the powershell script and took the input from release pipeline variables but same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below works perfectly with VSTS powershell task :

Store app name in variable :
[image]

```
$WebAppName = '$(WebAppName)'
write-host $WebAppName
foreach($servicename in $WebAppName.Split(','))
{
        write-host $servicename
}
```

Output :

```
2019-04-22T11:02:02.7680996Z devopstestwebapp1,devopstestwebapp2,devopstestwebapp3
2019-04-22T11:02:02.7737101Z devopstestwebapp1
2019-04-22T11:02:02.7750490Z devopstestwebapp2
2019-04-22T11:02:02.7765756Z devopstestwebapp3
```

Comment: The same will not work , if we take input from release pipeline variables instead of hard coding it in inline powershell. Try once

Comment: Try $WebAppName = '$(WebAppName)' to use VSTS variable. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am still not getting the correct output , instead of inline script , can u try the same by configuring the powershell script in azure powershell task

Comment: I test in both PowerShell Script and Azure PowerShell Script Task. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line is this one:

$WebAppName = $WebAppName.Split(',')

You are reassigning the result of split to the same variable $WebAppName which has been declared as a string in the parameter list. So the array result of Split will be cast to a string, not an array anymore.

The solution is to assign the result of split to a new variable:

$WebAppNameSplit = $WebAppName.Split(',')